# Django model owner field reading the log in user as None instead of the username

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I am trying to learn django rest framework and have been following the django-rest-framework tutorial. I am not able to understand why my model's owner field is taking None value instead of logged in user as it is a foreign key.

Please find my code below

my model

```
class Wish(models.Model):
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100,blank=True,default='')
    wishtext = models.TextField()
    owner = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', related_name='wishes', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)

    class Meta:
       ordering = ('created',)
```

If I don't use `null=True` its generating NOT NULL constraint error

my views

```
class WishList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):

    queryset = Wish.objects.all()
    serializer_class = WishSerializer
    permission_classes = (IsOwnerOrReadOnly, permissions.IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly)
    # print("object reached here  , permissions.IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly")

class WishDetail(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):

    queryset = Wish.objects.all()
    serializer_class = WishSerializer
    permission_classes = (IsOwnerOrReadOnly, permissions.IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly)
```

my serliazers

```
class WishSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    owner = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='owner.username')

    class Meta:
        model = Wish
        fields = '__all__'


class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    wishes = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=Wish.objects.all(), many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['id', 'username', 'wishes']
```

my object level permission

```
class IsOwnerOrReadOnly(permissions.BasePermission):

    def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):
        # Read permissions are allowed to any request,
        if request.method in permissions.SAFE_METHODS:
            return True

        # Write permissions are only allowed to the owner of the wish.
        return obj.owner == request.user
```

`print(obj.owner)` is showing `None` in the output and NULL in database, I couldn't understand the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have used `serializers.ReadOnlyField` for your `owner` field. This means that it will not be used when creating instances and will only be shown in serialized responses. Looking at your code you have then used this same serializer for your view inheriting from `ListCreateAPIView` which is the view I assume you use for creating objects. Hence it is no mystery that your field `owner` ends up being `None`.

Instead if you want to use the current logged in user as the one that made the object you can use [`SlugRelatedField` [DRF docs]](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#slugrelatedfield) to show the username, set it to be `read_only` and use pass it's `default` as [`CurrentUserDefault` [DRF docs]](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/validators/#currentuserdefault):

```py
class WishSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    owner = serializers.SlugRelatedField(
        # In case only the actual creator will be owner
        default=serializers.CreateOnlyDefault(serializers.CurrentUserDefault()),
        # In case editor can become owner
        # default=serializers.CurrentUserDefault(),
        read_only=True,
        slug_field='username'
    )

    class Meta:
        model = Wish
        fields = '__all__'
```

Comment: I am still receiving it as `None` even after modifying with your solution, I tried both current user and created user, also in the [tutorial docs https://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/4-authentication-and-permissions/ ] they used read only field in snippet serializer, but they are using APIView class and explicitly mentioned owner in `perform_create` function, where in my case I am using generics

Comment: @santhosh you need to create a _new_ instance of `Wish` here, since your old one (just delete them here) _doesn't_ have an owner.

Comment: Its still the same, I tried to remove all data and created new wish instances from Ui, but it still showing it as none in console and null in db, I wish i could post screenshot. Thank you for your support, I will let you know if I find a solution. I will go through all my settings and urls, I might be missing something.

Comment: I found the issue, now yours and tutorial code both are working, I commented the permission class `IsAuthenticated` in the settings.py,  ty